# ubuntu 15.10 after upgrade from 14.04 password invalid

Tags: linux, ubuntu-15.10

Every time I try to log in the password is invalid at login.

The password works ok in tty and boot etc. but not in log in screen. The guest session opens up ok. I tried altering password in grub menu: no joy.

I tried everything posted but no luck yet. Do you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: operating system ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Do you have any special character in your password?  Or, in other words: are you sure the layout of the keyboard in the graphical environment reflects your real keyboard? If you are not sure I will show you how to do it: what do you use, Gnome, KDE, Mate,... ?

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]
```

Comment: chmod:cannot access /home/[username]:No such file or directory

Comment: well I hope you substituted [username] with your username, I am sorry to have not mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: Command line having to use in tty1

Comment: Yes used my username

Comment: i am sorry was just confirming. This was the only way I knew, I will dig some more and let you know if I come across something.

Comment: try these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129246/after-12-04-upgrade-cant-log-in-although-password-is-correct, http://askubuntu.com/questions/161037/ubuntu-wont-log-in-after-update

Comment: @vernon: In that case, you can log in as root right? What's in `/home`? Maybe you have a separate partition for `/home` and somehow it doesn't get mounted on boot after upgrade, so the directory is empty now?

Comment: @JayT. Recursively changing the permission is a pretty bad idea btw